# convert mysql dump file to access db

Tags: ms-access, mysql

I have mysql dump file and I need to convert it to ms access, I have no access to phpmyadmin  so I can't use the programs that connect to the mysql db, so  I need for a software to convert mysql dump file to ms access db.
just i have this dump file in hand
thanks if you can help

Comment: I'm fairly sure you will need mySQL up and running, and import the dump there. Then you can worry about getting the data into Access. Installing mySQL shouldn't be too hard though.

Comment: There is [a thread about the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665855/loading-mysql-dump-or-text-file-into-microsoft-access-2003) on stackoverflow. Also there are commercial solutions to solve this task, for instance [DbConvert](http://dbconvert.com/convert-access-to-mysql-pro.php).